# Client Stub generated using Axis2 encoding xml data in SOAP:Body

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I'm facing issue with the Client Stub generated using Axis2.

It is encoding the the xml data that i send in the request.

param1valueparam2value

instead of converting it like

```
&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Param1&gt;param1value&lt;/Param1&gt;&lt;Param2&gt;param2value&lt;/Param2&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;
```

its converting it only to the below statement

```
&lt;Query>&lt;Param1>param1value&lt;/Param1>&lt;Param2>param2value&lt;/Param2>&lt;/Query>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to send a XML in soap body, then enclose it inside CDATA.

Modify the stub code and change the way how your stub create element

```
SOAPFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = factory.getDefaultEnvelope();    
OMElement xmlElement= factory.createOMElement("cdatatoservice", envelope.getDefaultNamespace());
envelope.getBody().addChild(xmlElement);

OMTextImpl omText = (OMTextImpl) xmlElement.getOMFactory().createOMText(xmlElement, xmlForCdata, XMLStreamConstants.CDATA);
xmlElement.addChild(omText);

System.out.println(envelope.toStringWithConsume());
```